# How to use genfromtxt with with brackets in format?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have a **csv file** with the following values:

```
# number,array1,array2
0,[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]
```

Now I would like to load these two arrays, but when i run:

```
new_array = np.genfromtxt(fname='file_name.csv',
           skip_header=1,
           defaultfmt=['%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i'],
           deletechars='[,]',
           usecols = (1,2,3,4,5),
           dtype=(int),
           delimiter=',',
           comments='# ',)
```

Then i get an array with values:

```
[-1  2  3  4 -1]
```

Instead of:

```
[1  2  3  4 5]
```

If I understand correctly, the problem are the brackets, but I expected that

```
deletechars='[,]'
```

would do the trick. How do I get **genfromtxt** to read these values correctly?

Comment: that's not a valid csv format

Comment: You could strip out the `[]` before hand, and give `genfromtxt` a file with 11 simple columns.  You can't tell `genfromtxt` to treat the `[,]` sequence as a differnt kind of delimiter.  It's designed to handle a csv, simple .comma separated values'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `deletchars` only affects the column names, rather than their data. I think you need a *"converter"* to remove the square brackets:

```
conv = lambda x: int(re.sub(b"[\[\]]", b"", x))
```

Then you can use:

```
In [84]: a = np.genfromtxt(fname='file.csv',
    ...:            skip_header=1,
    ...:            defaultfmt=['%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i','%i
    ...: ','%i'],
    ...:            usecols = (1,2,3,4,5),
    ...:            dtype=int,
    ...:            delimiter=',',
    ...:            comments='# ',
    ...:            converters={1:conv,2:conv,3:conv,4:conv,5:conv})

In [85]: a
Out[85]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sophisticated case you can load all arrays by regex parsing with [`numpy.fromregex`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html) and [`numpy.fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
rows = np.fromregex(test_txt, regexp=r'\d+,\[([\d,]+)\],\[([\d,]+)\]', dtype=[('c1', 'O'), ('c2', 'O')])
arr = [np.fromstring(c, sep=',', dtype=np.int32) for row in rows for c in row]
print(arr)
```

---

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int32)]
```